# Cannot remove items from Carpenter

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I can't remove items from Carpenter using item-ducts.

I have tried with and without power to the wood extract pipe. 
I have tried with the chest stuck directly onto the carpenter.
I have tried with peat, stirling and combustion engines. 
I've waited ages.

What am I missing from my setup?

This is my setup:
[image]

Pic 2 shows (I think) the first 4 wood pulp are made but I can neither extract manually or using wooden transport pipe to a chest.

[image]

Comment: Did you try with the chest on the other side? From what I can remember, you can only extract it's from carpenters from the right side.

Comment: I tried all sides. I looked at videos and duplicated their set-ups. I am running MC 1.7.10, Forestry 1.7.10-3.1.1.4, Buildcraft 6.0.18, and Industrial-Craft-2-Mod-Experiment-1.7.10. Could the IC2 be a conflict?

Comment: Tried other recipes as well. Googled until my eyes bled. Tried all sorts of different configurations. Need a lie down :(

Answer (score 2):

Your engine at the lower right isn't connected to the carpenter -- wooden kensis pipes need another pipe (stone keneisis or cobblestone kinesis are fine) between the wooden pipe and the thing receiving power.

You'll need a separate engine (just a redstone engine is fine), delivering power to the wooden item pipe.

Also, an extra stone/cobble item pipe between the wooden pip and the chest.

Comment: I cannot connect any input pipes to my Carpenter. But I have found that connecting the engine directly to the Carpenter makes the Carpenter work normally. So at least I have a working Carpenter. But I still have to figure out why I can't connect Kinesis pipes to the things I want to power - eg Carpenter, Thermionic etc. My thanks to those who answered :)

Comment: I hadn't got my head around the different types of power used in the different mods, but now I have. Thanks again all :)